# Difficulties scraping a table with R

Tags: r, rvest, scrape

I've been trying to scrape this website for information on cryptocurrency tokens: https://www.tokendata.io/# with R.The data I want is in the table that is presented on the main page.

The table is in a weird format that won't let me scrape with the usual methods I have been looking at -  with rvest as the main tool.

I believe this may be because this website is not entirely in HTML.

Does any one know how I could achieve a scrape of the table on the webpage aforementioned?

I'm quite new to this and I apologise if this question has been asked before.

Comment: I think you need something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html)

Comment: Okay thanks -  I'll take a look at that package